# Robot Framework: Disable Teardown Log into Test Message

Tags: robotframework

All of my tests usually have TearDown procedure, but some of the tests fails with terminal freeze or kernel panic, so that doesn't allow to run the TearDown and it returns errors that included in test messages, like that:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MultiSession                                                          | FAIL |
System crashed with Kernel panic

Also teardown failed:
Several failures occurred:

1) No match found for '
' in 700 milliseconds. Output:


2) No match found for '
' in 700 milliseconds. Output:


3) No match found for '
' in 700 milliseconds. Output:


4) No match found for '
' in 700 milliseconds. Output:


5) No match found for '
' in 700 milliseconds. Output:


6) '' does not contain '0'

7) No match found for '
' in 700 milliseconds. Output:


8) No match found for '
' in 700 milliseconds. Output:
```

How I can manage TearDown not to log the error into the Test Message?

Answer (score 2):

The best you can probably do is to place the following line at the beginning of your `Teardown`:

```
Run Keyword If     '${TEST_STATUS}'=='FAIL'    Set Log Level    ${NONE}
```

Note that it will still log all the keyword calls, just not anything inside those.

Being able to continue the test execution after failures was one of
the most requested features in RF2.5. You can find more information about this feature in the [Continue on failure](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/svn/tags/robotframework-2.5/doc/userguide/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#continue-on-failure) section of the User Guide.